# Will not ++ points into the database

Tags: php

I have a small problem is such that it will not update points in the database that is just them oven in spoken are in the database.

`$ _SESSION ["RankUP"]` is spoken as 3 content.

It will not equal 450 points oven in my other points that I have is I only have 21 points.

```
if($_SESSION["rankUP"] = 3) {
    if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE bruger SET rank=?, betal_dato=NOW(), point++450 WHERE `id`=?' )) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $rank, $id);
        $rank = $_SESSION["rankUP"];
        $id = $_SESSION["id"];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

will not be thrown some points up in the database at all.

Comment: can you clarify what your question is? it looks like a bunch of statements

Comment: What on earth is `point++450`?  I've never seen that operator used in SQL code or used in that structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
UPDATE bruger SET rank=?, betal_dato=NOW(), point = point + 450 WHERE `id`=?
```

`point++450` is not a valid way to express `point = point + 450` in any database system I know of.  This would generate a SQL syntax error.  (Use `print_r($stmt->error_info());` after `$stmt->execute();` to verify this.)

Comment: Props for decoding the question.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help, and i understand it's now!